# How to use Google Analytics to track a domain (and its subdomains) and a subdomain (as a separate instance)?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a domain that I track using Google Analytics. Soon, I will have a page on a subdomain that I wish to track separately, but also see its stats on the domain GA account. So:

- `example.com` account - tracks ("sees") all the traffic from itself **and** the
  subdomain
- `beta.example.com` account - tracks ("sees") only its own traffic

How do I set this up in the Google Analytcs admin panel? Is it possible to achieve?

**UPDATE**

OK, if I understand it correctly, I can take the same tracking code used on the domain and use it on the subdomain. Then, all I need to do is to **[create a view](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714?hl=en)** for the subdomain. However, after I did it and accessed the subdomain view, I could see the traffic from the domain as well, which I don't want. Does it take some time for the new view to start working properly, meaning: filter and sisplay just the subdomain traffic?

Comment: You'll need to show how you've configured your view filter. It should be an "Include" filter.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to @nyuen's comment, I've figured it out.

In Analytics, I've created a new view for the subdomain. Then all I did is I created an "include" filter for the view:

---

[image]

---

What this does is it filters the whole traffic from `example.com` to show only hits from `beta.example.com`.

Of course, you need the domain's tracking code on the subdomain page.

GA docs on how to create a view filter **[here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en&ref_topic=1032939#create_a_filter_at_the_view_level)**.